# Simple Yahoo Weather Api Not Working

Tags: api, yahoo, weather

I was using a simple code which includes a yahoo api code to get just the weather from my city and put in on my web page, however, i just read that yahoo public api is no longer working and i dont know how can a i get this code to work, i have a yahoo account, i created an api and i dont know how to proceed since here. If somebody can help me this is the code:

```
<?php
/*Clima*/
if(isset($_POST['zipcode']) && is_numeric($_POST['zipcode'])){
    $zipcode = $_POST['zipcode'];
}else{
    $zipcode = 'ARMA0056';
}
$result = file_get_contents('http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=' . $zipcode . '&u=c');
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);

//echo htmlspecialchars($result, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

$xml->registerXPathNamespace('yweather', 'http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0');
$location = $xml->channel->xpath('yweather:location');

if(!empty($location)){
    foreach($xml->channel->item as $item){
        $current = $item->xpath('yweather:condition');
        $forecast = $item->xpath('yweather:forecast');
        $current = $current[0];
        $clima = <<<END
           <span>{$current['temp']}&deg;C</span>

END;
    }
}else{
    $clima = '<h1>No results found, please try a different zip code.</h1>';
}
/*Clima*/
?>
```

Answer (score 10):

just replace `http://weather.yahooapis.com` with `http://xml.weather.yahoo.com`. credits to https://forum.rainmeter.net/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=23010

Comment: I'm just trying to get the XML request for a windows forms app, but I can't access the second XML link. For example, I'm trying to access http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss?p=68510 and it keeps saying it's invalid.

Comment: try with this query `select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places where placetype='Zip' AND text='68510' )`  `https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20%28select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places%20where%20placetype%3D%27Zip%27%20AND%20text%3D%2768510%27%20%29&format=xml`

Comment: This just stopped working, anyone happen to know another way?

Comment: @EricWeintraub https://www.igorkromin.net/index.php/2016/03/27/yahoo-effectively-shut-down-its-weather-api-by-forcing-oauth-10-and-crippling-it/

Answer (score 3):

xml.weather.yahoo.com was the solution, but the URL does not seem to be working anymore. Im now using yahoos query to get the XML i.e."https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%3D2489314"

This seems to be the same XML with the exception of "results" added to the tree.

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo recently updated the way they handle requests. It used to be just over any connection, but now to make it more secure and easier to handle, they recently opted into sending all requests over OAuth1. Use the sample code they provide on their page and get the information from the request over JSON.

See https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/ for more information.

Answer (score 0):

YAHOO changed some rules about api;
I made following class working for me... hope works for you;
$fcast=$phpObj->query->results->channel->item->forecast; change this line for other items...

```
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set('CET');
class weatherfc{
public $result;
function weather($city){
 $BASE_URL = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql";
 $yql_query = 'select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text="'.$city.'") and u="c"';
$yql_query_url = $BASE_URL . "?q=" . urlencode($yql_query) . "&format=json";
    // Make call with cURL
    $session = curl_init($yql_query_url);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $json = curl_exec($session);
    // Convert JSON to PHP object
  $phpObj =  json_decode($json);
  //var_dump($phpObj);
    $weatherd='<div> Weather In '.$city.'<br>';
    $fcast=$phpObj->query->results->channel->item->forecast;
    foreach($fcast as $witem){
    $fdate=DateTime::createFromFormat('j M Y', $witem->date);

    $weatherd.= '<div class="days">';
    $weatherd.= '<div class="item"><div>'.$fdate->format('d.m').'&nbsp;'.$witem->day.'</div><div class="image" style="width:90px !important; height:65px !important;"><img src="http://us.i1.yimg.com/us.yimg.com/i/us/nws/weather/gr/'.$witem->code.'d.png" width=90></div></div>';
    $weatherd.= '<div><span>'.$witem->high.'&deg;C</span>';
    $weatherd.= '<span>'.$witem->low.'°C</span></div></div>';
    };
    $this->result=$weatherd;
}

}

$h= new weatherfc;
$h->weather("Antalya,Turkey");
echo $h->result;
?>



    <style>
    .days{
    width:90px;
    font-size:12px;
    float:left;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border:#999 1px dotted;
    }

</style>
```