# Yahoo weather API updated one not working

Tags: api

I was using yahoo weather API, the latest updated one which is :

http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss?z=?

but it is not working for the last 2-3 days.

Can anyone let me know if there is any kind of update to this as I am not able to find it on yahoo's site or anywhere else.

Comment: [Look at answers at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36242098/simple-yahoo-weather-api-not-working/36798701#36798701)
I hope My PHP class will help you...

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo enabled OAuth1 on their weather API sometime around March 25 2016.

You can use their documentation to update your code.
https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/#get-started=

[image]